# Display complete content of shell/terminal screen in the front end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, text

I am  using Angular in front end and node as server to create a web application. After starting  my web server I want to capture all the contents appearing on the shell terminal and display in front end.

For example: If some processing is occurring displayed on shell terminal, all content should be stored in a file at web server so I can  display in my front end. How can this be done ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to be able to read the Node terminal from the front end?

Comment: Yes , I want to display the nodjs console logs in the Front end.